# How is the contents loaded on this wesite(woolworths.com.au)

Tags: html

I know they use xhr to load products, but couldn't figure out how they load the left panel, i.e.

```
    <div id="left-panel"
         class="closed u-noOutline"
         wow-open-close-panel="left"
         wow-open-close-panel-sr-text="navigation"
         tabindex="-1"
         ng-show="isLeftPanelVisible()">
        <div class="left-panel-content" ui-view="left-panel" oly-angulax-view="navigation-panel"></div>
    </div>
```

[link: https://www.woolworths.com.au/](https://www.woolworths.com.au/)

Would appreciate if someone can give some hits.

Comment: Did you see any JavaScript?

Comment: @ScottHunter haven't checked js yet. You mean they might hardcode the contents in js?

Comment: I think @ScottHunter is trying to hint that you haven't really given us enough to go on here. we know you are confused about loading the left panel but that's about it. and though you left a link to the webspage you didn't leave us the code which is generally what is asked here so that we can decipher things and leave it around for the next person with teh same problem.

Comment: @SemicolonsandDuctTape I might not get your point, but let me explain: If you go the the webpage you will see 'fruit & veg', 'bakery' etc and their subcategories ('fresh fruit' etc). These contents were stored in the div (left panel) I posted above. However in the html file, the div is empty. So there must be some way to load these contents. My question is what's the way. I hope this make the question a bit clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They've added some javascript to the page which builds the info you're looking for. Look at the source and find the line which starts with:
    `window.wowBootstrap`

That's the line which contains the data for the left div (and more)

Comment: Thanks mate. I checked all separates javascript files but forgot the script embeded in the html.